# Checking/stowing luggage in London for a stopover visit

Tags: london, luggage-storage

We were planning to travel to India from New York, but we wanted to visit London/Scotland for three days. We are fine as far as the UK visa is concerned, but the problem is with the luggage. We don't want to reclaim the luggage and check in later. What is the best way to handle this?

Comment: Welcome to Travel.SE. I edited your question title to more accurately reflect what I believe your actual question is; if I have misinterpreted it, please do not hesitate to roll back. You may get some ideas from *[Flying into London, overnight train to Edinburgh that evening, where to stow bags/shower?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52557)* and *[Cheap places to store bags in London for a few hours?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/14612)* as I doubt any airline would take your luggage for two days.

Comment: You need to specify which airport you're flying to/from, as there are 4 major ones in London. As of now this question is too broad.